# How to Update Extension settings preferences from JS - Safari API?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

i am using safari extension settings to add a checkbox to the extension prefrences.
[image]

i want to remove the check box check from the code by using this:

safari.extension.settings.setItem("testProperty",false);

i see that the value is updated when i use it in code. but the UI isn't updated till the next Safari restart.

Do you know if there is a way to make the sync when i change the value from the code

thanks
Tal

Comment: Safari won't update the checkbox if that settings page is active (showing on screen, even if behind another window). If the prefs window is closed or you have opened it to a different settings page, the checkbox will reflect the current value of the setting once that page is opened. There is nothing you can do to make the checkbox update while it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use applescript for that purpose.